# Prove $\int_{0}^{1}{x\arcsin(x) dx} \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus

I know how you can show this geometrically, but is there any way to prove this algebraically?

Answer (score 4):

Since $\arcsin x$ is bounded above by $\pi / 2$, by monotonicity of the integral we have
$$\int_0^1 x \arcsin x dx \leq \frac \pi 2 \int_0^1 x dx = \frac \pi 4$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two known inequalities
$$x \leq |x|$$ and $$\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx\right|\leq \int_a^b|f(x)|dx.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1x\sin^{-1}xdx &\leq \left|\int_0^1x\sin^{-1}xdx\right|\\
&\leq \int_0^1x|\sin^{-1}x|dx\\
&\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1xdx=\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*}